# If $P=\tan(3^{n+1}\theta)-\tan\theta$ and $Q=\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\sin(3^r\theta)}{\cos(3^{r+1}\theta)}$,

Tags: trigonometry

If $P=\tan(3^{n+1}\theta)-\tan\theta$ and $Q=\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\sin(3^r\theta)}{\cos(3^{r+1}\theta)}$,then relate $P$ and $Q$

---

$Q=\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\sin(3^r\theta)}{\cos(3^{r+1}\theta)}$
$=\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\sin(3^r\theta)}{\cos(3.3^{r}\theta)}=\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\sin(3^r\theta)}{4\cos^3(3^{r}\theta)-3\cos(3^{r}\theta)}$
I do not know how to change into telescoping series.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\tan3A-\tan A=\dfrac{\sin(3A-A)}{\cos3A\cos A}=\dfrac{2\sin A}{\cos3A}$$

Do you recognize the Telescoping nature?

**Related** : [Show that $\frac{\sin x}{\cos 3x}+\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 9x}+\frac{\sin 9x}{\cos 27x} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\tan 27x-\tan x\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344505/show-that-frac-sin-x-cos-3x-frac-sin-3x-cos-9x-frac-sin-9x-cos-27)